# How to change Mozilla Developer Tools theme

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I recently updated to Firefox 49 and I don't like the new color scheme *(green and grey)* introduced for the DevTools.

Can anybody tell me how to switch to the old DevTools theme *(dark , orange , blue)*?

Answer (score 37):

You can [select a theme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings#Choose_DevTools_theme) for the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) through the [settings page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings).  You get to the settings page by clicking on the gear-like icon near the top left (fourth icon in from the left) of the DevTools.  It looks like:

[image: Select DevTools Theme]

If those are not sufficient, you will need to look for an add-on which will provide the theme you desire, write one yourself, or make changes to [your userChrome.css file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Modifying_the_Default_Skin) ([answer with code changing the position of the DevTools inspector breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355927/3773011)) with the CSS you desire. For the appropriate CSS classes, you could look in `chrome://devtools/skin/dark-theme.css`, or one of the other CSS files with DevTools themes.

Comment: Is there a user.js flag for this? Can't seem to find one. How does Firefox keep track of which devtools theme is selected?

Comment: Answering my own question it's `devtools.theme` set to  `"light"` or `"dark"`.

Comment: hey Makyen I love your theme it looks like Nord theme... I would love to use it.